# python pandas 'reverse' substring search

Tags: python, pandas

Given a long string `name = 'Mary had a little lamb'`

and a pandas Series with  `pd.Series(data=['Mary', 'large', 'little lamb'])` ,

is there a pandas string operation that could identify whether an entry is a substring of the longer string `name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think there is one. You would need to iterate:

```
s = pd.Series(data=['Mary', 'large', 'little lamb'])
name = 'Mary had a little lamb'

[x in name for x in s]
```

output: `[True, False, True]`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the different items in the Series using `for`-loops (or list comprehensions to make it more concise) and check if each item is in the long string using `in`:

```
name = 'Mary had a little lamb'
for string in pd.Series(data=['Mary', 'large', 'little lamb']):
    if string in name:
        print(f"'{string}' is in long string")
    else:
        print(f"'{string}' is not  long string")
```

Output:

```
'Mary' is in long strong
'large' is not  long strong
'little lamb' is in long strong
```